# MySQL Connection Pool for mysql client

Tags: mysql, client, pool

Is there a way to have an established connection pool on the client side (running as daemon), so it can be used by the mysql client on linux?

mysql ==(named pipe/unix domain socket?)==> mysql connection pool (daemon) ==> mysql server

Comment: why would you what to do that? for my pov it sounds like a security risk

Comment: To give the ability to scripts that cannot have a connection pool to re-use an established connection. There are a few scripts that are opening a connection each time they are executing a SQL statement (calling mysql client). Having short connections, you are facing 2 problems: high (system) cpu for creating and terminating these connections and secondly the number of TIME_WAIT sockets (tcp_tw_recycle and tcp_tw_reuse are not an option).

Comment: i posted a answer , let me know if it helps you or not

Answer (score 0):

After reading the response from you i can propose the following solution:

- to have a daemon application (resident in memory) which will accept connections from clients (via sockets or http)
- the clients will sent a security token (so that they can be authorized) and the query that needs to be executed
- the daemon application can have a pool of mysql connections (fixed number) and it will choose a connection (depending on the load) to exec the queries and return the result (if necessary )

This way you will have full control on the number of mysql connections also you will have a single point where the communication with the db layer is made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I have in my mind, but I was wondering whether there is something like this already implemented. MySQL Proxy, which is still in pre-stable phase, doesn't support versions prior to 5.

Comment: i see, well why son't you upgrade Mysql ? because `MySQL Proxy` sounds exactly like you need

Comment: The only explanation I can give is because people are are reluctant to change... Thanks Stephan, I appreciate your help!

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I've encountered this type of narrow minded ppl before . In this case you can make the implementation yourself and i recommend using java for development :). I'm glad that i was able to help. Cheers!